# Onchange event of Select Control in Blazor app (net8) is not firing

Tags: select, blazor, onchange, .net-8.0, onselect

I am newcomer to blazor and writing a blazor web app.  I would like to run some logic after the user has made a selection in the select control.  I have tried both onchange and onselect events .  The event is not firing.  I will appreciate if someone could help me here.

```
@page "/"

<select id="ABC" @onchange="GroupSelected">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
<hr />
<label>@SelectedGroup</label>

@code
{
    string SelectedGroup = "Z";
    public void GroupSelected()
    {
        SelectedGroup += "A";
        StateHasChanged();
        return ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor tutorial: @onclick event doesn't work in new razor components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77495740/blazor-tutorial-onclick-event-doesnt-work-in-new-razor-components)

Comment: Also see this question and answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593425/onafterrender-not-fired-on-layout-level-net-8

Answer (score 0):

after the @page directive, add..
@rendermode InteractiveServer

it tells the compiler to interactively communicate with the server (where the C# code resides)

Hope it helps..

Comment: also, don't forget to restart the application after this change.. !!